# what type of electronics job would combine mathematics, electronic design and programming into one

Tags: digital-logic, analog, embedded, math

There are quite a few different areas of jobs in the Electronics industry.
We have Analogue, Digital, Embedded, Telecommunications, Control and much more. What I wish to know is that what job would combine Mathematics (lots of maths involved) with circuit design and programming (could be low level C/C++ or even high level .Net and Matlab) into the same role?

Sorry I wish I knew of a better place to post this type of question. I know the question is rather vague, but I am just asking for opinions.

Comment: If you are an electronics engineer you might have learnt along the way to do all the above and be employed to do all the above as well. I don't believe there is a specific job title for someone with all these skills. In fact I would say that if you went for an interview with a particular company that defined the job as analogue but no digital/programming then they don't understand what person they are looking for.

Comment: After graduation I worked in control systems testing the controls for various aircraft systems. No math. No design. Basic programming (script writing). Then I got another job to do some hardware stuff. But because the company was smaller, I had to put on a math, design, and programming hat. As @Andyaka said there is no type of job that does that but a smaller company will give you more hats to wear than a large company.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advanced Math in day to day Electronics?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43138/advanced-math-in-day-to-day-electronics)

Comment: If you are seriously asking what part of electrical engineering requires math, then the answer is pretty much all of it, as with most types of engineering.  However, parts of EE that seem to be more match analisys intensive that others include signal processing and control systems, at least of the ones I tend to bump into.

Comment: Designer of digitally-controlled switchmode power supplies. Google "ELMG"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a job title for this, but it can happen that people end doing all of that, even though probably not everything at the same time.

For an example I worked for a company developing stereo-camera systems ("3D cameras"). There was a lot of math for the stereovision part, of course for the implementation of the algorithms there was a lot of programming involved, and some of the cameras were working on embedded platforms so there was some hardware-design on some projects. The team-lead had some understanding in all those disciplines, and was working in all of them. The team members were more specialised (mathematician/programmer/electronician).